# What is the specific fuel consumption and cruise thrust of PW1521G engines?

Tags: engine, fuel, thrust

I'm looking for the specific fuel consumption (SFC) and thrust related to PW1521G in cruise regime, as well as the associated assumptions for these ratings. I can't find them online.

Comment: "The" cruise thrust is whatever you need for "this" flight, at your planned cruise speed & altitude & gross weight. Change any of those parameters & the cruise thrust will change accordingly. This question looks to be unanswerably vague to me. VTC.

Comment: Gosh, I'd like to think that the answer to the OP ought to be found at the P&W website...

Comment: [EASA type certificate](https://www.easa.europa.eu/sites/default/files/dfu/EASA%20TCDS%20IM%20E%20090_PW1500G_Issue8_20210224.pdf) for the engine. Note that SFC and thrust in "cruise conditions" is something commonly found in literature since pretty all flights will be conducted in optimum (economically speaking) conditions for cruise, eg [here is a comparison of RR engines SFC/trust/altitude... for cruise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/91DOi.png), [source](https://booksite.elsevier.com/9780340741528/appendices/data-b/table-3/default.htm). To me it's a valid question.

Comment: These are data that are commonly found in the literature, but I have failed to find them for this Pratt & Whitney engine. This is why I'm picking the brain of this forum. I'll put a bounty on this question once it's available.

Comment: "*I have failed to find them*", me too, but this is a valid question, that was my point. It would be better if you could adjust your question, the stack is ran in strict mode and good questions are often closed because they are not asked with all explicit details. E.g. here the manufacturer has designed the engine using some cruise conditions that need to be provided with the answer.

Comment: Have voted to re-open this question. It is a valid question, related to Aviation. All pilots understand what cruise conditions are.